# CSS Нестандартный text-align, как выровнять?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

При верстке с шаблона столкнулся с таким не стандартным выравниванием текста.
[image: Выравнивание текста]
Анализатор psd шаблона сломался, и показывает невалидное значение `text-align: justifyLeft;` Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое сверстать, что б оно выравнивалось и по правому краю, и что б отступы были.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section_2__box {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-right: 94px;
  max-width: 620px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.section_2__box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -38px;
  left: -80px;
  padding: 38px 0 82px 80px;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(215, 191, 191, 0.74);
  z-index: -1;
}

.section_2__box p {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: end;
  letter-spacing: 0.36px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="section_2__box">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat,
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum
    quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: text-align: right; по правой стороне, " и что б отступы были" а это я не понял что вы хотите

Comment: `text-align: justify` и задать максимальную ширину и/или отступы…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как такое сверстать, что б оно выравнивалось и по правому краю, и что б отступы были

Предложу такой вариант...

В стилях я пометил добавленные свойства комментарием.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section_2__box {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-right: 94px;
  max-width: 620px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.section_2__box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -38px;
  left: -80px;
  padding: 38px 0 82px 80px;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(215, 191, 191, 0.74);
  z-index: -1;
}

.section_2__box p {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.36px;
  z-index: 3;
  /* добавил */
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: left;
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section_2__box">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat,
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum
    quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Не помешало бы ещё добавить `text-align-last: left;`, на всякий случай :-)

Comment: @UModeL, как скажешь - добавил.